# chrome.tabs.create/executeScript > call function that belongs to the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome and the problem I'm having is I need to be able to call a JavaScript function that belongs to the webpage that's opened in the tab.

For details, the website is my website, therefore I know that function does exist. That function does a lot of things based on a string value. I want the user to be able to highlight text on any webpage, click a button from the Chrome extension that automatically loads my webpage and calls that function with the highlighted text as it's value.

Here's what I got so far:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://mywebsite.com" }, function (tab) {
    var c = "initPlayer('" + request.text + "');"; ////'request.text' is the highlighted text which works
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: c });
});
```

But Chrome console says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: initPlayer is not defined."

I know that function does exist as it is in my code on my own website.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because ***pages* and *content scripts* run inside two separate javascript contexts**. This means that content scripts cannot acces functions and variables inside a page directly: **you'll need to inject a script into the page itself to make it work**.

Here is a simple solution:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://mywebsite.com"}, function (tab) {
    var c = "var s = document.createElement('script');\
        s.textContent = \"initPlayer('" + request.text + "');\";\
        document.head.appendChild(s);"
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: c});
});
```

**NOTE**: since January 2021, use [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/) with [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) instead of `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`.

With the above code you will basically:

1. Create the tab
2. Inject the code (variable `c`) into it as a content script that will:
3. Create a script with the code you want to execute on the page
4. Inject the script in the page and, therefore, run its code in the page context